# Move file from jFileChooser to folder inside src

Tags: java

I'm trying to move a file that i got from `JFileChooser` to a folder inside my `/src/`, but its not copying and not returning the correct path.

Here it's what i got.

```
JFileChooser abrir = new JFileChooser();
File file = abrir.getSelectedFile();

File newPath;
try {
    newPath = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("catalogos/").toURI());
    File movedFile = new File(newPath+"/"+file.getName());
    System.out.println(movedFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());
} catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(FrmPrincipal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

I used before inputstream to get the path to a folder inside the src folder, and it worked well.

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("folder_name")
```

Running the project, the file doesnt go to the correct folder, neither the print of the path is correct.

```
\build\classes\catalogos\filename.ext
```

Whats the problem?

Comment: *"I'm trying to move a file that i got from JFileChooser to a folder inside my /src/"* - `src` won't exist at runtime. Even worse, if the program is packaged into a Jar, there won't be any directories, it's just a zip file. You "could" copy the file into a relative location based on the current execution context of the program, which might make it available to `Class#getResource` but you'd need to test that

Comment: From the looks of your output, you're using NetBeans, which doesn't run it's code from the context of the jar, but runs it from the context of the `\build\classes` directory within the project

Comment: well, how can you explain me using `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("folder_name")` for a folder inside /src/ and it works during the current execution? The file structure is `/src/folder/`.

Comment: BUT, 'src` WON'T exist when you package and deploy the program

Comment: Well, whats the correct way to deal with resources like this? Create a folder inside the root path or on a specific location?

Comment: That depends, why are you trying to copy something into the application context like this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Well, i would like to be able to import files somewhere to use on my DAO and there i will be able to use it on JAXB. I would like too to be able to access the folder to see which files are in there.

Comment: In most case, it's usually more appropriate to store files in the `{user.home}` directory, on windows that would typically be `{user.home}\AppData[Roaming/Local]\{you app name}` or simular

Comment: And if i would like some files to come with the .jar by default?

Comment: Then manually copy the files into the src directory or update the build script to include them

Comment: Oh, now i understand. The files inside `/src` will be compiled and the functions im using can access them. But, in runtime, if i want to copy files there, i wont be able, because /src/ wont exist. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folders indide `/src/` will be compacted with the .jar and wont exist during the runtime, altought you can refer to things inside of it just if you put contents inside there before you compile you jar, so you will be able to access content inside. But, during the runtime, you aren't able to put files inside the `/src/anything`, you can create a folder inside the `/user/youfolder` with the `System.property(user.home)`. That's what i did.